# mongoimport errors when importing to CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am using `mongoimport` to import documents into CosmosDB and its failing within seconds with error

```
2020-05-10T14:24:01.669+0100    Failed: bulk write error: [{[{Error=16500, RetryAfterMs=28, Details='}]}, {<nil>}]
2020-05-10T14:24:01.669+0100    126 document(s) imported successfully. 1 document(s) failed to import.
```

I have already set throughput to a max of 10,000 both at the DB level and at collection level but it failed with the same error. I understand that there's a preview feature that enables server side retries? Or is there another way to solve this?

Comment: Since `mongoimport` isn't aware of the retry return values (http 429 along with retry time window), this would require either a larger RU increase during import, *or* using a different import tool which does handle retries (such as Azure's Data Factory, which natively supports MongoDB, or JSON, as input, and Cosmos DB via MongoDB API as an output).

Comment: I'm from the Mongo API team on Cosmos DB. Email me chrande (_at_) microsoft (__dot__) com with your subscription id and database account name, and I can get SSR enabled on your account (or open a support ticket asking for as much if you don't wanna trust a stranger on the internet). We're rolling out the self opt-in feature soon (and new subscriptions are being opted in by default)